# Python Oracle, Conexión mediante una clase

Tags: python

alguno sabe por qué no me acepta la cadena de conexión?, me da el siguiente error

invalid syntax. Maybe ypu meat '==' or := instead of = ?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
class BDMicrofzs(object):
    dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn("x.x.x.x","xxxx",service_name = "xxxx")
    conn_str = (user = "usuario", password = "contraseña", dsn = dsn_tns, encoding = "UTF-8")
    def __init__(self, connection_string = conn_str):
        self.connection_string = connection_string
        self.connector = None
    def __enter__(self):
        self.connector = cx_Oracle.connect(self.connection_string)
        return self
    def __exit__(self,exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
        if exc_tb is None:
            self.connector.commit()
        else:
            self.connector.rollback()
        self.connector.close()



def LimpiarTabla():
    with oracle_connection() as conn:
        limp = ("delete from temp_sol",conn)
```

Comment: El valor de conn_str tiene una sintaxis no valida. Cual es el objetivo de esa linea?

Comment: Es como si intentaras crear una tupla, pero usas el operador de asignación dentro de cada item. Eso no tiene sentido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto está mal:

```py
conn_str = (user = "usuario", password = "contraseña", dsn = dsn_tns, encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Le estás asignando una tupla a una variable, pero esa tupla tiene nombres sin definir: `user`, `password` ...

La forma recomendada por [la documentación](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#easy-connect-syntax-for-connection-strings) es:

```py
dsn = cx_Oracle.makedsn('el_server', 1521, service_name='la_instancia')
self.connector = cx_Oracle.connect(user='el_user', password='el_passw', dsn=dsn, encoding='UTF-8')
```

Pero si insistes en usar una cadena de conexión, puedes [usar esta forma](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50897127/1545868):

```py
host = 'el_server'
user = 'el_usuario'
# ... etc
# Y luego:
conn_str = f'{user}/{password}@{host}:{port}/{service}'
```

Comment: disculpa @aeportugal sabes donde pueda conseguir un ejemplo para crear una clase que me permita manejar la conexion a una base de datos en oracle, pues debo de hacer varios select e insert, pero no quiero es estar en cada funcion declarando todo, vi un ejemplo, pero la verdad no lo entendi muy bien.